# How to set Schema in the Python Postgres connector?

Tags: python, amazon-redshift

I am trying to write to DB tables and currently hardcoding the schema name in every query i.e. `awesome_schema.book`. Unfortunately, now I have to set this schema name in all the queries :-(
Is there a way to set it in the connector or cursor level and not tangle the queries with schema name.

Can anyone please suggest what would be the option for my case.

How to set the *schema* while running code from python.

```
import redshift_connector

# Connects to Redshift cluster using AWS credentials
conn = redshift_connector.connect(
    host='examplecluster.abc123xyz789.us-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
    database='dev',
    user='awsuser',
    password='my_password'
 )

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("create awesome_schema.Temp table book(bookname varchar,author‎ varchar)")

cursor.execute("select * from awesome_schema.book")
```

That's how I am setting schema to `awesome_schema` in the code.

But this is super tedious and not configurable. Of course, I can manipulate the string and set schema.

But I am wondering is there a better way to set `Schema`?

Details:

- I am using redshift_connector - [Amazon Redshift connector for Python >= 3.5](https://github.com/aws/amazon-redshift-python-driver)
  I have already looked into the https://github.com/aws/amazon-redshift-python-driver repo but have not found many suitable examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redshift (and PostgreSQL) has the `SET search_path TO some_schema` syntax that might be a possible solution for your use case.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_search_path.html