# How to set a particular schema when connecting to Postgres using pyodbc while setting engine without setting search_path in query?

Tags: postgresql, pyodbc

I am trying to query Postgres SQL Database using Pyodbc.

Now, I want to set a particular schema while setting up the pyodbc connection itself, so that I do not have to add the schema name in every query.

Now one solution is to add a search path - [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605066/how-to-set-schema-in-the-python-postgres-connector).

Is there a way to modify the `pyodbc.connect()` itself so that the search path is set during engine initiation itself?

I tried:

```py
# Assume there is a dictionary called choice with details.
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
        database=choice["database"], 
        schema=choice["schema"],  # Tried Adding Schema Here.
        user=choice["username"], 
        password=choice["db_pass"], 
        host=choice["server"], 
        driver=driverName
        )
```

And also

```py
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER='+driverName+';SERVER=' + choice["server"] + ';DATABASE=' +
    choice["database"] + ';SCHEMA=' + choice["schema"] + ';UID=' + choice["username"] + ';PWD=' + choice["db_pass"]
)
```

When I run the query `select current_schema()` it still returns `public` in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ALTER ROLE` or `ALTER DATABASE` to change the default setting of `search_path` for a user or a database.

Comment: So, the way the project is setup. There is one point of import (where pyodbc engine is imported and initiated), and is used multiple times in different scripts. So, we want to make a single change at the import and initiation level only.

Comment: And that change could be to run a single SQL statement.